# Registration - Thank you page Error - Call to undefined method -Joomla

Tags: civievent, joomla, registration

Joomla 3.9.14 and Civi 5.20 / 21  registration has been running fine for years with various different combos of Civi and joomla 
The full error is: Call to undefined method CRM_Core_BAO_UFGroup::getFrontEndTitle()

User is registered to the event - just an error page where a thank you page should be - any thoughts were to look.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At administer - system settings - directories, there's one called custom php path that contains a folder path. Go look in that path in the filesystem and you probably have a customized version of CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php. It will need to be updated with some recent changes that were made to the real CRM/Core/BAO/UFGroup.php, in particular the addition of the function getFrontEndTitle().

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was an issue with an extension CiviGrant - Since our site no longer uses this - it was disabled. Thank you to Brian Shaughnessy for the recommendation.